# another javascript redirecting

Tags: javascript, php

My view :

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Admin Login</h2>
        <input type="text" id="inputUsername" name ="inputUsername"
               class="form-control" placeholder="Admin" required autofocus />
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only"> Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword"
               class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="login"
                type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My controller :

```
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['inputUsername'];
        $password = $_POST['inputPassword'];

        echo "<script>window.location.href = 'collections.php';</script>";
    }
```

When I clicked the button,
it doesnt redirect me to collections.php , what I missed here ?

Comment: is your php controller fires?

Comment: It is not a correct way to redirect user. Use `header('Location: collections.php', true)`. It will redirect a user using HTTP header instead of JavaScript which can actually be disabled or suppressed on purpose.

Comment: what framework you use?is it codeigniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use php header to redirect the page ,it's easy and better compaire to what you did here.
       header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Answer (score 0):

you redirect from php

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['inputUsername'];
        $password = $_POST['inputPassword'];
        header('Location: collections.php'); //<------- php redirect to other page
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please add a bit explanation

Answer (score 0):

this is what you were trying outputting JS in PHP for redirection be careful with url if you use relative

```
$redirectURL = "../controller/collection.php";
print("<script>");
print("var t = setTimeout(\"window.location='".$redirectURL."';\", 3000);");
print("</script>");
```